# How to call a column by combining a string and another variable in a python dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, between

Imagine I have a dataframe with these variables and values:

| ID | Weight | LR Weight | UR Weight | Age | LS Age | US Age | Height | LS Height | US Height |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 63 | 50 | 80 | 20 | 18 | 21 | 165 | 160 | 175 |
| 2 | 75 | 50 | 80 | 22 | 18 | 21 | 172 | 160 | 170 |
| 3 | 49 | 45 | 80 | 17 | 18 | 21 | 180 | 160 | 180 |

I want to create the additional following variables:

| ID | Flag_Weight | Flag_Age | Flag_Height |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 1 | 0 | 1 |

These flags simbolize that the main variable values (e.g.: Weight, Age and Height) are between the correspondent Lower or Upper limits, which may start with different 2 digits (in this dataframe I gave four examples: LR, UR, LS, US, but in my real dataframe I have more), and whose limit values sometimes differ from ID to ID.

Can you help me create these flags, please?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you write a function that takes a row as input and returns the flags?

Comment: You can find unique bound combinations - separate each of bound column pairs from the rest of dataframe, then remove duplicate rows, reset index, index is now category. Then run function to find the category for each of your properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use reshaping using a temporary [`MultiIndex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.html):

```
(df.set_index('ID')
   .pipe(lambda d: d.set_axis(pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(
                     d.columns.str.extract('(^[LU]?).*?\s*(\S+)$')),
                              axis=1)
        )
   .stack()
   .assign(flag=lambda d: d[''].between(d['L'], d['U']).astype(int))
   ['flag'].unstack().add_prefix('Flag_').reset_index()
)
```

Output:

```
   ID  Flag_Age  Flag_Height  Flag_Weight
0   1         1            1            1
1   2         0            0            1
2   3         0            1            1
```

Answer (score 0):

So, if I understood correctly, you want to add columns with these new variables. The simplest solution to this would be [df.insert()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html).

You could make it something like this:

`df.insert(number of column after which you want to insert the new column, name of the column, values of the new column)`

You can make up the new values in pretty much everyway you can imagine. So just copying a column or simple mathematical operations like +,-,*,/, can be performed. But you can also [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) a whole function, which returns the flags based on your conditions as values of the new column.

If the new columsn can just be appended, you can even just make up a new column like this:

```
df['new column name'] = any values you want
```

I hope this helped.